# adding dates to a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I currently have a df in pandas with a variable called 'Dates' that records the data an complaint was filed.

`data = pd.read_csv("filename.csv") 
Dates
Initially Received
07-MAR-08
08-APR-08
19-MAY-08`

As you can see there are missing dates between when complaints are filed, also multiple complaints may have been filed on the same day. Is there a way to fill in the missing days while keeping complaints that were filed on the same day the same?

I tried creating a new df with datetime and merging the dataframes together,

```
days = pd.date_range(start='01-JAN-2008', end='31-DEC-2017')
df = pd.DataFrame(data=days)
df.index = range(3653)
dates = pd.merge(days, data['Dates'], how='inner')
```

but I get the following error:

```
ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 
'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
```

Here are the first four rows of data

[image: data]

Comment: Yes, and you can see that the dates go from 08-APR-08 to 19-MAY-08, so the dates between April 8th and May 19th are not in the dataframe. I would like to keep the current entries in 'data' but add the dates that are currently missing as empty rows (there are other variables in the 'data' dataframe).

Comment: sorry, I had to do a screen shot. there are 27 variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, there's an issue with your input

First do:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', skiprows = 1)
```

Then

```
days = pd.date_range(start='01-JAN-2008', end='31-DEC-2017')
df_clean = df.reset_index()
df_clean['idx dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df_clean['Initially Received'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=days, index = range(3653), columns=['full dates'])
dates = pd.merge(df2, df_clean, left_on='full dates', right_on = 'idx dates', how='left')
```

Comment: Thanks, however, though all the dates are filled in I lose all the other data from the dataframe 'data'...

Comment: hmm, that makes no sense. Try removing the fill_value parameter

Comment: I think you may also run into `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` since 'multiple complaints may have been filed on the same day.'

Comment: I took about the fill_value parameter but now the cells are filled with NaN instead of zeros.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean about merging the data.

Comment: Thanks, but the data frame is still only filled with NaNs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181448/discussion-between-yuca-and-graham-streich).

Answer (score 0):

Create your date range, and use `merge` to outer join it to the original dataframe, preserving duplicates.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

TESTDATA = StringIO(
"""Dates;fruit
05-APR-08;apple
08-APR-08;banana
08-APR-08;pear
11-APR-08;grapefruit
""")

df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=';', parse_dates=['Dates'])

dates = pd.date_range(start='04-APR-2008', end='12-APR-2008').to_frame()
pd.merge(
    df, dates, left_on='Dates', right_on=0,
    how='outer').sort_values(by=['Dates']).drop(columns=0)

#   Dates       fruit
#   2008-04-04  NaN
#   2008-04-05  apple
#   2008-04-06  NaN
#   2008-04-07  NaN
#   2008-04-08  banana
#   2008-04-08  pear
#   2008-04-09  NaN
#   2008-04-10  NaN
#   2008-04-11  grapefruit
#   2008-04-12  NaN
```